# Changing the value for RadioGroupFieldEditor

Tags: java, swt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set/Get values for RadioGroupFieldEditor in SWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199127/set-get-values-for-radiogroupfieldeditor-in-swt)

I have a RadioGroupFieldEditor field and a browse for selecting the data type in my application, User can select the radio button for datatype or can select a new datatype using browse button.
If the user selects a radio button and then clicks on browse button, i want to remove the selection for RadioGroupFieldEditor. How can i do this

Comment: what about btnYourRadioBottn.setSelection(False); in the widgetselection event of you browse button

Comment: [Set/Get values for RadioGroupFieldEditor in SWT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199127/set-get-values-for-radiogroupfieldeditor-in-swt)

Comment: @Dinup: rdiogroupfieldeditor doesnt have setSelection()

Comment: @BAZ: I have already seen this. I dont want to set or get vlue. I want to remove selection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the selection of the individual `Button`s by iterating over the children of the `RadioGroupFieldEditor`. This is a little hacky, but I don't see an easier way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    String[][] radioButtonOptions = new String[][] { { "Button1", "button1" }, { "Button2", "button2" } };

    final RadioGroupFieldEditor radioButtonGroup = new RadioGroupFieldEditor("PrefValue", "Choose Button1 or Button2", 2, radioButtonOptions, shell, true);

    Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    button.setText("Deselect");

    button.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0) {
            Composite temp = radioButtonGroup.getRadioBoxControl(shell);
            Control[] children = temp.getChildren();

            for(Control child : children)
            {
                if(child instanceof Button)
                {
                    ((Button)child).setSelection(false);
                }
            }
        }
    });


    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```